# big oh of algorithm with nested loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o, nested-loops

find the big oh characterization

```
input: n  

s<-0  
for i<-1 to n^2 do  
  for j<-1 to i do  
    s<-s+i
```

Both loops iterate `n^2` times. I'm not sure if I should add or multiply the loops. Right now I think the answer is `O(n^4)`.

Comment: Perhaps to validate this you could look at how s varies with n to get more of an idea of whether O(n^4) is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer loops `i` from 0 to `n^2`, while the inner one loops `j` from 1 to `i`.

Thus, the inner loop has complexity of `i` (inner loop needs `i` steps, `i` is varying). Let us denote the runtime of the inner loop by `IL(i)=i`.

To get the total runtime, we see that the inner loop is executed `n^2` times with varying "parameter" `i`. Thus, we obtain as total runtime:

```
 n^2           n^2
----          ----
\     IL(i) = \    i 
/             /
----          ----
 i=1           i=1
```

That is, you have to sum up all numbers from 1 to `n^2`. There are many basic textbooks explaining how to evaluate this.

The result is `(n^2)(n^2+1)/2`, which leads to an overal complexity of `O(n^4)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct the answer is `O(n^4)`. First the inner loop cost `i`. Then the outer loop cost `sum(1->p) i = p(p-1)/2`, where `p=n^2`. Which gives a cost of `O(n^4)`

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is *almost* correct.

The number of loop iterations:

```
1 + 2 + ... + n^2 
= (n^2+1)*(n^2)/2
= (n^4 + n^2)/2
```

So the answer is `Θ(n^4)` (as a side note it also is `O(n^4)`).

You can prove that formally by choosing three constants `c1`, `c2` and `n0` such that:

```
c1*n^4 <= (n^4 + n^2)/2 <= c2*n^4 forall n >= n0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the maximum value of `i` is `n^2`, that gives us `O(n^2) * O(n^2)` which is equal to `O(n^4)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check simply the [basic sum formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_+_2_+_3_+_4_+_%E2%80%A6). Your sum goes not to N but N^2 which gives you

```
n^2(n^2+1)/2
```

and this is indeed O(n^4)